# Why does C# use int for indices and random numbers?

Tags: c#

Why does C# use int for indicing of elements for example `result = arr[(int)index];`?
This is for me illogical because indices can't be negative.

The same is also true for example for `int rand = random.Next((int)max)`, why is the parameter an int even if it can't be negative?

Comment: actually, in a multi-dimensional array (don't use them) indicies can be negative.

Comment: Why *not*? What's wrong with an `int` convention?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow.

Comment: As p.s.w.g. commented, the answer is in that post.  But some indexes can be negative as stated in that answer.  `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` can be -1, and I would be willing to bet others as well.